# audio duration is undefined

Tags: javascript, for-loop, nan, html5-audio

I'm trying to make a simple web app for audiobooks listening. And I'm trying to set a timeline length. I wanted to do it by summing up duration of all chapters. But when I do it this way:

```
let timelineLength = 0;
let chapterLength;
currentPart.forEach(chapter => {
    chapterLength = chapter.duration;
    timelineLength += chapterLength;
});
```

chapterLength is NaN so timelineLength is also NaN.
When I type chapters[index].duration in chrome console after the app's been loaded it works just fine. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: without knowing what `currentPart` Array even is, and how it is related to `chapters` Array, it's going to be hard to help. But, are you even waiting for the resource to be playable before trying to analyse it? there's events emitted when loading media that will help you determine when such information *may* be available

Comment: "_When I type chapters[index].duration [...] it works just fine_" You are not looping over `chapters` though. You are looping over `currentPart`.

Comment: For now it's just a div with a bunch of audios as children
`
<div class="book">
    <audio src="./audio1.mp3"></audio>
    <audio src="./audio2.mp3"></audio>
    <audio src="./audio3.mp3"></audio>
</div>
`

and in js :
`let currentPart = document.querySelectorAll('.book audio');`

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
currentPart.forEach(chapter => {
    chapter.addEventListener('loadeddata', () => {
    chapterLength = chapter.duration;
    timelineLength += chapterLength;
    });
});
```

I had to wait for the data to load.